# How to Import Data or Synchronize Data in isolated Storage of WINDOWS PHONE 7.1 to a SQL Server Database engine?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7.1

I wish to develop an Windows phone application which will be working in a remote area with no internet connectivity, so I need to store the data in phone and when I back at home I need to  retrieve this data and update this to SQL Server engine at home.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you buy a book on Windows Phone 7 development and some blog posts about the subject.

Windows Phone 7 has **SQL Server Compact Edition** witch is placed into the isolated storage.

as a pointer, start with this blog post

[Windows Phone 7.5 - **Local SQL Database**](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.1-Local-SQL-Database.aspx)